# Lightning combobox with "new record" Interaction

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I need to implement a combobox like on the next img:

[image: lightning combobox with interactions]

Until now Im using this line of code:

```
<lightning:inputField variant="label-stacked" fieldName="Contact"/>
```

I have read the whole documentation I Found, But cant find the way to see the "New Contact" option who shows a form to add a new Contact.

Thanks a lot for your help.

PD: I took the image from other stackexchange question to help me to explain what I need.

*** ##############  Edit 1:  ##############################***

I need to add the next information:
I have a form with some fields.
This field in particular is not part of the "tobe saved" object but I need this field to do something in the controller.

My real need is just have a combobox/select who shows the available records and show the option "New Object" to add a new one if the availables are not enough.

I was reading the documentation and cant find salesforce out of the box implementations.

Answer (score 1):

`lightning:inputField` doesn't support new Record creation feature, if you need new record creation function you should use `force:inputField` component it uses `UI API`  [check out my answer here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/267472/65412)

Comment: THanks for your contribution!
i'll check it con monday and mention de result.

Comment: sdandamud1 i just tested your idea, but i've just realized that this field is not part of my customObject where i need to store the selected value.

I Edited my Cuestion